# Changing the format of files in linux

Tags: command-line, bash, loop-device

I have a bunch of files with .vcf suffixes, comma separated and containing " like below

```
"","CHROM","POS","ID","REF","ALT","QUAL","FILTER","INFO","FORMAT","NORMAL","TUMOR","Depth","DistanceToAlignmentEnd","DistanceToAlignmentEndMAD","DistanceToAlignmentEndMedian","HomopolymerLength","LowMapQual","MMQSDiff","MapQualDiff","MapQualDiffMedian","NT","QSS","QSS_NT","ReadCount","ReadCountControl","Repeat","SGT","SNVCluster10","SNVCluster100","SNVCluster20","SNVCluster5","SNVCluster50","SOMATIC","StrandBias","TQSS","TQSS_NT","VariantAlleleCount","VariantAlleleCountControl","VariantAlleleFrequency","VariantBaseQual","VariantBaseQualMedian","VariantMMQS","VariantMapQual","VariantMapQualMedian","VariantStrandBias","normal","tumour","N_DP","N_FDP","N_SDP","N_SUBDP","T_DP","T_FDP","T_SDP","T_SUBDP","T_REF_COUNT","T_ALT_COUNT","N_REF_COUNT","N_ALT_COUNT","T_VAF","N_VAF","N_AU_1","N_AU_2","N_CU_1","N_CU_2","N_GU_1","N_GU_2","N_TU_1","N_TU_2","T_AU_1","T_AU_2","T_CU_1","T_CU_2","T_GU_1","T_GU_2","T_TU_1","T_TU_2"
"1","chr1","11195689",".","C","G",".","PASS","Depth=83;DistanceToAlignmentEnd=38.75;DistanceToAlignmentEndMAD=9.00;DistanceToAlignmentEndMedian=37.50;HomopolymerLength=2;LowMapQual=0.00;MMQSDiff=136.94;MapQualDiff=-8.750e-01;MapQualDiffMedian=0.00;NT=ref;QSS=16;QSS_NT=16;ReadCount=83;ReadCountControl=49;Repeat=0;SGT=CC->CG;SNVCluster10=0;SNVCluster100=2;SNVCluster20=1;SNVCluster5=0;SNVCluster50=2;SOMATIC;StrandBias=0.482;TQSS=1;TQSS_NT=1;VariantAlleleCount=4;VariantAlleleCountControl=1;VariantAlleleFrequency=0.048;VariantBaseQual=40.00;VariantBaseQualMedian=41.00;VariantMMQS=157.25;VariantMapQual=59.00;VariantMapQualMedian=60.00;VariantStrandBias=0.250","DP:FDP:SDP:SUBDP:AU:CU:GU:TU","49:1:0:0:0,0:47,48:1,1:0,0","82:0:0:0:0,0:78,79:4,4:0,0","83","38.75","9","37.5","2","0","136.94","-0.875","0","ref","16","16","83","49","0","CC->CG","0","2","1","0","2","SOMATIC","0.482","1","1","4","1","0.048","40","41","157.25","59","60","0.25","list(DP = ""49"", FDP = ""1"", SDP = ""0"", SUBDP = ""0"", AU = ""0,0"", CU = ""47,48"", GU = ""1,1"", TU = ""0,0"")","list(DP = ""82"", FDP = ""0"", SDP = ""0"", SUBDP = ""0"", AU = ""0,0"", CU = ""78,79"", GU = ""4,4"", TU = ""0,0"")","49","1","0","0","82","0","0","0","78","4","47","1","0.0487804878048781","0.0208333333333333","0","0","47","48","1","1","0","0","0","0","78","79","4","4","0","0"
```

How I can convert the comma space to tab, removing ", removing the first column and finally save the cleaned file as .txt with the base name of matched original file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `csvcut` and `csvformat` from the Python-based `csvkit` package ex.

```
for f in *.vcf; do csvcut -C 1 "$f" | csvformat -T > "${f%.vcf}.txt"; done
```

Comment: @Angel it looks like you are trying to use `pip` (or `pip3`)? There's no need to do that - you can install `csvkit` from the Ubuntu *universe* repository using `apt`

Comment: You are amazingly helpful , thank you